# Is it possible to make a partition devoted to the softwares installed?

Tags: partitioning, software-installation, software-sources

I had to reinstall my OS.

One the most deseagreable part is to reinstall the softwares in it (mongo, eclipse, and so on).
That's why I want to know if I can make a partition dedicated to softwares? And will it be efficient? I mean, in default installation, there are many files that go to */ect*, */bin*, in the root system actually.

So, if I had to reinstall my OS once again; or other case change for Kubuntu, Xubuntu; will I have to reinstall the softwares anyway? Because it will be dependent of */etc*'s files in the root, or it will have a "parallel" system organisations with binaries files in the softwares dedicated partition?

Comment: Unfortunately you'll have to reinstall again. There's a way to list all softwares installed by APT and then sort of automate the reinstallation in the new OS but that's not the case for the software you mentioned.

Comment: I find that keeping notes on exactly how to properly install each complex application makes repairs and (inevitable but rare) reinstalls very, very easy.

Comment: Ok, that's very clear. Thank you.

Comment: make a post install script. I did that for years and it worked pretty well during unit. Now budgie got it almost 100% correct for me in default apps and my post install is just a few lines.

Comment: @Rinzwwind it seems to be a geat idea. I will study it. Thank you.